# Suggestion for learning Javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to learn JavaScript. For this recently I had purchased a book named “*JavaScript The Good Parts*” from OReilly’s. Though this book is pretty old, but I got some good feedback about this book. I want to learn to write plain JavaScript code from scratch and then move to jquery. Is there any suggestion with this vision?

I have another question, just for curiosity --- is it possible to use JavaScript or jquery for developing desktop application inside?

Comment: Go here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info and scroll down to the "Learning Javascript" section

Comment: But is there any sequence if i want to be a master in javascript ... i mean what is the most wanted things/topics that a javascript master must learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*JavaScript The Good Parts* is a great book for Javascript, I wouldn't recommend it for learning the language. You should come back to it once you understood the concepts of the language.
As @PitaJ already mentioned in the comments you should take a look at the learning section here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

And yes, it is possible to develop desktop applications. However you will need software that allows you to do that. i.e.: http://appjs.org/ or http://www.tidesdk.org/
Speaking from a quality point of view, software developed like this will probably never reach the level of natively build applications.
You might also find the [node.js](http://nodejs.org) project interesting.

**EDIT:** Windows 8 also allows you to build desktop Javascript application. [MSDN Javascript Apps for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you search on Google then there are so many tutorial sites like

For JavaScript

1. http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
2. http://www.echoecho.com/javascript.htm
3. http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/
4. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/index.htm
5. http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/

For jQuery

1. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp
2. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

And there are lots of tutorials and PDFs for these, but you can start from the above urls

Or refer answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Answer (score 1):

Try: 
1. http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp - w3schools' javascript tutorial
2. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp - w3schools' jquery tutorial

These will give a idea of both javascript and jquery.

Once you are familiar with jquery, you can also visit: http:// api.jquery.com/

This is the official jquery api "blog".